# Parse.com JS - Update row with Pointer-column

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using Parse and JavaScript.

I know the ObjectId from the *Status_id*-class but is not able to update the column in *Question_status*-class because it is a Pointer-type

How should I update a Pointer column with JavaScript..

```
var Answer = Parse.Object.extend("Question_status");
    var answer = new Answer();
    answer.id = question_status_id;
    answer.set("answer", selectedAnswer);
    answer.set("status_id", "duMW5p8Dh3");

    answer.save(null, {
      success: function(answer) {
        //console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + answer.id);
        $.mobile.changePage( "#finish", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false });
      },
      error: function(answer, error) {
        console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically create a pointer, the same way you are with question_status:

```
var answer = new Parse.Object("Question_status");
answer.id = question_status_id;
answer.set("answer", selectedAnswer);

var status = new Parse.Object("Status_id");
status.id = "duMW5p8Dh3";
answer.set("status_id", status);

answer.save(...
```